# How can I improve my standing with the Pope?

Tags: medieval-2-total-war

In Medieval 2 Total War, your standing with the Pope / Papacy is an extremely important factor.  What choices impact your standing with the pope?  Does the number of churches and priests I have even matter?

Comment: I love the question titles on Gaming...

Comment: Sending him flowers each year seems to help

Comment: @IvoFlipse wrong genre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [GameFaqs strategy guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/931592-medieval-ii-total-war/faqs/49193), the following works for maintaining a good relationship with the Pope:

"Doing missions for the Pope, not fighting other Catholics, and giving the Pope
large sums of money are good ways to maintain a healthy relationship with him."

The strategy guide also mentions assassinating the Pope to try to get someone more favorable to you to be the Pope and bribery for when you get excommunicated.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, replace him with a friendly pope.  Barring that, large sums of money.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the number of **churches** and **priests** matter. If your relationship with the Pope is at rock bottom, you can send him **gifts**, then **ally** with him, etc. **Crusades** in which you where active also count for your standing with the Pope.